# Move flag from one script to another in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 powershell  scripts `script1.ps1` and  `script2.ps1`. They both contain the same parameter flag and integer parameter `[int]$num, [switch]$silent = $false`.

Now I call `script.ps1` with parameters `script.ps1 222 -silent`. I want to call `script2.ps1` from `script1.ps1` with that flag and another integer parameter. But the only decision I found is

```
param([int]$num, [switch]$silent = $false)

if($silent) {
    .\script2.ps1 333 -silent 
} else {
    .\script2.ps1 333
}
```

Is there more brief and convenient way to send parameter flag from one script to another ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch parameters accept boolean values, so you could do something like this:

```
Param(
    [int]$num,
    [Switch]$silent = $false
)

.\script2.ps1 333 -silent:$silent.IsPresent
```

Note that this doesn't behave exactly like a passthru. The second script in this case will always be passed the parameter `-silent`, just with an explicit value of `$true` or `$false.

If you want to not pass the parameter when your first script wasn't called with it you can't get around actually making that distinction. In that case you need something like this:

```
Param(
    [int]$num,
    [Switch]$silent = $false
)

$extraParams = @{}
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('silent')) {
    $extraParams['silent'] = $silent.IsPresent
}

.\script2.ps1 333 @extraParams
```